# How to transform Seq[Option[A]] into Seq[A]?

Tags: scala

I want to filter a `Seq` for `Some` option types, and extract the contents.

Is there a single function call to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val list = optionList.flatMap(_.toList)
```

As sschaef points out in the comments, you can use `flatten`:

```
val list = optionList.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

```
optionList.collect { case Some(x) => x }
```

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm tempted to choose your answer. It seems far more idiomatic. Anyone else want to weigh in on which one is preferable?

Comment: I would say that this one is way more clear to someone who will read the code while `flatten` looks a litte more "magic" and is a little confusing.